# Submit Form Via Ajax in Rails Error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to submit some form via ajax call and I have written the following code but I am getting the error undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class

```
  <%= form_for :url=>articles_editcomment_path ,:method=>:post ,:remote => true do |f| %>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
```

how do I overcome the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning the model or variable for form:

```
<%= form_for :article, :url=>articles_editcomment_path ,:method=>:post ,:remote => true do |f| %>
```

Above method will not require a variable of `Article` type and will not populate your form in editing mode.

**OR**

```
<%= form_for @article, :url=>articles_editcomment_path ,:method=>:post ,:remote => true do |f| %>
```

Above method will require a variable named `@article` which will may be initialized in controller and will populate the form in editing mode.

If this doesn't solve the problem feel free to ask for more

Comment: what is the difference between the two approaches if you can elaborate

Answer (score 0):

[**form_for**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

The problem you have is you're using [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and *not* passing an ActiveRecord object - which is why your error is appearing as follows:

> undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class

Notice what you're passing to the `form_for` method - a *hash*.

--

What you *should* do is populate the form with an ActiveRecord object. This is how Rails *builds* the ActiveRecord forms with `form_for` -- it takes data from the object itself & then builds the form off the back of it

So to fix your problem, you **need to populate your form with an ActiveRecord object**:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
Class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
       @article = Article.find params[:article_id]
       @comment = Comment.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/comments/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for [@article, @comment] do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```